# ajax post to node.js express app?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I'm trying to authenticate before using ajax to insert into a database

```
$('#button').click(function () {       
  $.post('/db/', { 
   stuff: { "foo" : "bar"}
  }, callback, "json");
});
```

Here's my node.js code:

```
server.get('/', function(req,res){
console.log(res);
  res.render('index.ejs', {
    locals : { 
              header: '#Header#'
             ,footer: '#Footer#'
             ,title : 'Page Title'
             ,description: 'Page Description'
             ,author: 'Your Name'
             ,analyticssiteid: 'XXXXXXX' 
            }
  });
});
```

^^ this part works ok. It comes from a boilerplate, I can go to localhost and see the front page.

This next part is supposed to be where the mongo insert happens. This gives me a 404.

```
server.on('/db/', function(req,res){
    console.log(req);
    console.log(res);
    var db = new mongo.Db( 'dbname' , new mongo.Server( 'localhost', 20003, {}), {});   
    db.open(function (err) {
        db.collection('testCollection', function (err, collection) {
            collection.insert(res.stuff);
        });
    });
});
```

What I'm trying to do is insert the object `stuff` into testCollection.

Right now I'm getting a 404 on /db/

I'm sure this is very wrong. I don't think I'm supposed to use server.on, server.get doesn't work either. Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `server.post`, since you're doing a [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) request via jQuery.

`server.on` will add a event listener to the server, in this case for the non-existent `/db/` event, which never gets triggered by anything.

Please take your time and make sure to read the express.js [Guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), the Node.js [API Docs](http://nodejs.org/api.html) might come in handy too.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're expecting a post, your /db/ handler should be defined in a `server.post` method.  You're getting a 404 because the server doesn't have a route defined for the combination of POST and /db/.

Answer (score 1):

you also should be authenticating the db connect and shouldn't be reconnecting to the db on each request

```
var db = new mongo.Db( 'dbname' , new mongo.Server( 'localhost', 20003, {}), {});
db.authenticate(user, password, function({ // callback }));

server.post('/db/', function(req,res){
  db.open(function (err) {
    db.collection('testCollection', function (err, collection) {
      collection.insert(. . .);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: I think there's a typo in the authenticate function?

Comment: Thanks I've moved the new mongo.db outside of the request callback, but i can't get the authenticate function outside and have it still work.